# How do I know a row label of a series of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, series

A CSV file is given. I am supposed to print the name of the row label of a row of the data frame as a string output. How do I do that?

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_csv('olympics.csv', index_col=0, skiprows=1)
s= df.loc[df['Gold'].idxmax()]
return s.index
```

Here 'Gold' is a random column index name. I have been trying by this code. But it only prints column indices. But I need to print the row index output as a string .

Comment: `df.loc[df['Gold'].idxmax()].name`??

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'], 
                     'A':['foo','bar','foo','bar','foo','bar','foo','foo'],  
                     'C':[10, 10, 10, 30, 50, 60, 50,  8], 
                     'D':[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]},
                    index = list('abcdefgh'))
```

`idxmax()` returns the row index,

```
>>> df['C'].idxmax()
'f'
```

Selecting that row produces a Series whose name is the index of that row.

```
>>> df.loc[df['C'].idxmax()]
id      6
A     bar
C      60
D       4
Name: f, dtype: object

>>> df.loc[df['C'].idxmax()].name
'f'
```